# IJ Idea - navigate from SQL to database

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to navigate from native SQL query to database object (table or field name), having only JDBC driver as dependency? I know it possible for JPA (at least it work with spring data module and with annotations such as @Table or @Column), and as I remember, it work for native SQL. But currently I have no JPA.

Here is visual explanation of my goal:

[image]

PS I already setup dialect, query become green but when I click on "users" table, it shows "cant' find declaration to go to"

Answer (score 0):

alt-enter - uninject language reference

alt-enter - inject language reference

Look like small bug here - if you are setup database connection at first, file will be marked with "generic sql dialect" flag, and SQL queries will be treated as "something-sql-like", but not connected to your database.